# group_by and conditionally mutate + count

Tags: r, dplyr, group-by, tidyverse

I have the following example data frame (the original has more than 200,000 rows:

```
df <- tribble(~ id, ~ birth_year,
                 1,         2015,
                 1,         2015,
                 1,         2016,
                 2,         2008,
                 2,         2010,
                 3,         2010,
                 3,         2014,
                 3,         2014,
                 3,         2014,
                 4,         2010,
                 4,         2011,
                 4,         2012,
                 4,         2013)
```

I want to group by id and count how much times a birth year is repeated with the id. Ideally obtaining this:

```
df_wanted <- tribble(~ id, ~ birth_year, ~ n,
                        1,         2015,   2,
                        1,         2015,   2,
                        1,         2016,   2,
                        2,         2008,   0,
                        2,         2010,   0,
                        3,         2010,   3,  
                        3,         2014,   3,
                        3,         2014,   3,
                        3,         2014,   3,
                        4,         2010,   0,
                        4,         2011,   0,
                        4,         2012,   0,
                        4,         2013,   0)
```

Any suggestions? I came across conditionally counting specific values but no repeated cases like my example.

Comment: Hi @Paula, I think there is a mistake in your output (`n` column) : either the two and the three should be ones and twos respectively, or the zeros should be ones. Does this make sense?

Answer (score 1):

When you say, "group by id and count" do you mean aggregating?
if so, I believe this would do the trick:

```r
df %>% 
  count(id, birth_year)
```

If you mean you want to add a column with the counts of id and birth year (like your `df_wanted` shows), the the `add_count` function is what you're looking for:

```
df %>% 
  add_count(id, birth_year)
```

You can learn a lot of this from the [R for data science book](https://r4ds.had.co.nz/), or the dplyr documentation.

Answer (score 0):

With `dplyr` you can try the following. If there are no duplicates, will set `n` to zero. If there are, then use `table` to get frequencies of `birth_year`, and then use `mutate` to store the `max` number.

```
library(dplyr)

df %>%
  group_by(id) %>%
  mutate(n = ifelse(anyDuplicated(birth_year), max(table(birth_year)), 0))
```

**Output**

```
      id birth_year     n
   <dbl>      <dbl> <dbl>
 1     1       2015     2
 2     1       2015     2
 3     1       2016     2
 4     2       2008     0
 5     2       2010     0
 6     3       2010     3
 7     3       2014     3
 8     3       2014     3
 9     3       2014     3
10     4       2010     0
11     4       2011     0
12     4       2012     0
13     4       2013     0
```

---

An alternative with `data.table` which may be faster:

```
library(data.table)

setDT(df)[, n := ifelse(anyDuplicated(birth_year), max(table(birth_year)), 0), id]
```

---

Or base R:

```
within(df, { n <- ave(birth_year, id, FUN = function(x) ifelse(anyDuplicated(x), max(table(x)), 0)) })
```